# How to read the complete path till the end of the directory structure using loop in scripting

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I have a following directory structure as 
**/home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/divider.txt**, **/home/ABCD** this is like a root directory for my apps, I can get that easily, and from there all the sub folders may vary for every case, so I am looking for a generic program where I can extract the path through some loops

I want to extract the directory structure to a separate variable as **"/home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/"**
Can any one help me

2nd Example : **/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/user.txt**
variable should get the following value - **"/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dirname`

```
$ dirname /home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/divider.txt
/home/ABCD/apple/ball/car
```

To assign to variable do

```
var=$(dirname /home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/divider.txt)
echo "$var"
```

No spaces before and after the `=`

Comment: When I start, I wont be having the complete path /home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/divider.txt, I need to start from /home/ABCD and move until the end of the structure and extract the full path, Is there a easy way to traverse to the end of the folder structure, Because the folder strcuture changes for every request

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. If you want all the directories under your home, do `find $HOME -type d`. If you want the prefix trimmed, do `(cd $HOME; find . -type d)`

Answer (score 1):

if the ending slash `/` is required, you could pick one:

```
kent$  echo "/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/user.txt"|grep -Po '.*/'        
/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/
```

or

```
kent$  echo "/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/user.txt"|sed -r 's#(.*/).*#\1#'
/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/
```

or

```
kent$  echo $(dirname /home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/user.txt)"/" 
/home/ABCD/adam/nest/mary/
```

Comment: When I start, I wont be having the complete path /home/ABCD/apple/ball/car/divider.txt, I need to start from /home/ABCD and move until the end of the structure and extract the full path, Is there a easy way to traverse to the end of the folder structure from /home/ABCD, Because the folder structure changes for every request